# Part of mesh/object rendering on top of another

Tags: rendering, render-layers, clipping

I've been working in creating a forest scene and I'm trying to use these flowers I found online. I'm pretty new to blender so I'm not sure if I'm just missing something or what. When I import the object it's render properly, however when I apply the texture, the leaves render over the top part of the flower. I made sure to check that the viewport display settings were set to in front. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have set your materials' Blend or Shadow modes to `Blend`.

Try setting them to `Hashed` or `Clipped`:

[image: blend modes]

[Material Settings — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode)